# jqGrid sorting not working when i use field name as field_name

Tags: sorting, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid  4.3.1. My problem is sorting column in grid using name as item-id does not work.

```
$col["name"] = "item-id";
```

But if I use like this, sorting column in grid works fine.

```
$col["name"] = "itemid";
```

If i use "-" or "_" in field name sorting doesn't work. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you don't use any special charackters in `name` value. You don't posted enough details about the grid which you creates, so I try to guess. If you loads the data from the server and you use `repeatitems: false` style (named properties for the data which represents rows) then you can use `jsonmap` with the name used on the server and use another name for columns:

```js
name: "itemid", jsonmap: "item-id"
```

If you use *server side* sorting (without `loadonce: true`) then you can use `index` which corresponds server names, but use another `name` value:

```js
name: "itemid", index: "item-id"
```

If your problem exist **in your server code only** then you could try to enclose special characters in `[]` or `""` characters during building SQL statements. The choice between `[]` or `""` depend on the database which you use.

Comment: Great help @Oleg This worked for me $col["name"] = "itemid";
$col["jsonmap"] = "item-id";